# In Perl,is there a way to do simple arithmetic inside quotes?

Tags: perl

```
$i = 5;
print "{$i*10}";
```

Sometimes I may need to do things like above,but Perl doesn't interpret it the way I want,and I can only do it with another variable.Is there a trick?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$i = 5;
print "${\($i*10)}";
```

or

```
print "@{[$i*10]}";
```

These interpolate a "variable" that is a dereference of a code block that contains a reference of the appropriate type (scalar in the first instance, array in the second).

Another way would be to have a dummy hash that always returns the key as a value:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    package Tie::Hash::Dummy;
    use Tie::Hash;
    use parent -norequire => 'Tie::StdHash';
    sub FETCH { $_[1] }
    tie our %Lookup, __PACKAGE__;
}

my $i = 5;
print "$Tie::Hash::Dummy::Lookup{$i*10}";
```

Another way would be to use the `\N{}` character name lookup interface, though this will bind variables from a different location, and at compile time (as well as using string eval, potentially a security issue):

```
my $i;
BEGIN { $i = 5 }
BEGIN { $^H{'charnames'} = sub { eval $_[0] } }
print "\N{$i*10}";
```

(This *might* work better if the charnames handler returned an overloaded proxy object that performed the eval upon stringification, but I don't have time to try it.)

Yet another way would be to set a string-constant handler with overload::constant().

Comment: \ has higher precedence, so that takes a reference to $i and multiplies it by 10, then uses the result of that as a symbolic reference.  You need to take a reference (and then dereference with `${}`) to the entire expression: `"${\( EXPR )}"`.

Comment: are you sure `\( EXPR )` isn't interpreted as reference an array,but evaluates the same as reference a scalar since it has only one member?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  () in perl never creates a list or an array of the contents, it just affects precedence.  That said, \\() is a little special in that it returns a list of references to the elements contained in (), but in your case there's only one.

Comment: never? `@arr = (1,2,3);`,what about this one? My doubt is that whether `()` is creating a list or as a bracket ?

Comment: The only thing the parentheses do there is cause the lower-precedence , to happen first.  Without them, `@arr = 1,2,3` becomes `(@arr = 1),2,3`.   () does not create lists.

Comment: Note that `$x[1+2+3]` gives the index 6 element (ie, the 7th element) of `$x`. I think this is different, but related to your code block example above.

Comment: @barrycarter I don't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you use "printf":

```
printf("%s",$i*10);
```

That'll do.

Comment: With all the other options out there, this one is correct 99.999% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 5;
print "${\($i*10)}";
```

not that I recommend doing that!

**update**: it is (more or less) equivalent to:

```
$i = 5;
$j = ($i * 10);
$k = \$j;
print "${$k}";
```

Comment: Perl interpolates dereferences as `${EXPR}` and `@{EXPR}` so all you have to do is to write an expression returning a reference to the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following ,

```
print "{". $i*10. "}";
```

Comment: I want to do it within quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access a hash?

If not, then simply use:  print "{".($i*10)"}";